# Posting variables in different pages using PHP to Create Dynamic Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding dynamic tables in html and php. My goal is to create a dynamic table that displays the queried data from mysql and displays them in a table with checkboxes so the user can select questions from a question bank and then do something with them. My problem however is getting the data to be displayed. Using a certain type of mvc architecture, I need to keep the sql out of the front end html and php portions. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as how to post the variables from the back end(mysql query) and send them to the front end(html and php section) via curl where I can dynamically create a table with checkboxes. I have attempted the solution using bootstrap and combining sql with html and php as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

include('ProfessorWelcome.php');
//set up mysql connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
//select database
mysql_select_db("username", $con) or die(mysql_error());


?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="author">
    <link href="" rel="shortcut icon">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="tablefilter.js"></script>

    <title>Registration form</title><!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />








</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<form role="form" action="#" method="POST" name="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well">
            <h2 class="text-center">Question Bank</h2>
            <hr width="70%">


                <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%" style="visibility:hidden;" align="left"></th>
                            <th width="20%" align="left">Question</th>
                            <th width="20%" align="left">Difficulty</th>
                        <!--    <th width="7%" align="left">Last Name</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="center">Email</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="center">Gender</th>
                            <th width="7%" align="left">BirthDay</th>  -->


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            //select all records form tblmember table
                            $query = 'SELECT Question, Difficulty FROM QuestionBank';
                            //execute the query using mysql_query
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            //then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' /></td><td>".$row['Question']."</td><td>".$row['Difficulty']."</td>";

                            }   

                        ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script language="javscript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand half you're asking. But the fact that you seem to want some quite advanced functionality and still use `mysql_*` instead of `mysqli_*` or `PDO()`, makes me wonder if this is actually even written by you. It just doesn't add up. Anyway. Could you clerify your question by explaining the end-result you're expecting? Keeping the SQL out of the front end, sounds like you gonna need ajax techniques to me.

Comment: @icecub This was written by me and it was written as a mock up to the overall picture which is basically separating the sql from the front end and still achieving the same result. Basically, there is a front-middle-back architecture and the sql has to remain in the back and send the variables to the front to utilize in the creation of making a dynamic table with check boxes with those values. I hope that cleared up some things.

Comment: It is not that difficult.  I understand what you want.

Comment: It probebly isn't that hard. I just don't understand anything about `curl`, which is probebly why I didn't understand the question. Still the use of `mysql_*` and a low points account got my spider senses tingling. Sorry about that xD It kinda felt like "He knows what he's talking about, yet does something not very smart. What's going on here?" Again, apologises :)

Comment: @icecub I've been doing full scale web apps since 1996.  I still use mysql.  I have not hit a point where I have needed a feature in msqli that is not working in mysql.  mysqli is a work in process and has had security issues.  I cannot afford to unnecessarily use mysqli for no good reason and risk another security vulnerability.  If it ain't broke, I do not fix it.  Did you steal my cat?

Comment: You don't have to explain your actions to me. Using mysql to query non-user data is perfectly fine. Even to query user data is perfectly fine if you know what you're doing. Personally I just prefer relying on prepared statements instead of all the hassle with regex etc. Each his own I guess. Oh, and yes. It explains it's face! :P

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

I added the `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` so the Top of the page is being transmitted as you create the table.

Moved `<title>` to immediately follow `<head>`

**Very Important:** Moved CSS above JS in the `<head>`

I used heredoc syntax:  [PHP Manual Heredoc Syntax](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Added `MYSQL_NUM` to:

```
mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM))
```

`$row[0]` and `$row[1]` can be used in a double quoted string without concatenation dots.   Can also be used in here doc.  `$row['Question']` and `$row['Difficulty']` can not.

Do you realize the overhead associated with jQuery? You do not need any JS in this page. But you created a lot more work for the Browser and are making the visitor wait while the Browser does all that unnecessary work.

I would 86 the JS and jQuery.  And NO Bootstrap.  Learn CSS.

```
<?php ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
include('ProfessorWelcome.php');
echo <<<EOT
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Registration form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="author">
  <link href="" rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="tablefilter.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></script>

  <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form role="form" action="#" method="POST" name="form">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well">
      <h2 class="text-center">Question Bank</h2>
      <hr width="70%">
          <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th width="5%" style="visibility:hidden;" align="left"></th>
                      <th width="20%" align="left">Question</th>
                      <th width="20%" align="left">Difficulty</th>
                  <!--    <th width="7%" align="left">Last Name</th>
                      <th width="7%" align="center">Email</th>
                      <th width="7%" align="center">Gender</th>
                      <th width="7%" align="left">BirthDay</th>  -->
                  </tr>

              </thead>
              <tbody>
EOT;
ob_flush();

//set up mysql connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
//select database
mysql_select_db("username", $con) or die(mysql_error());




                      //select all records form tblmember table
                      $query = 'SELECT `Question`, `Difficulty` FROM `QuestionBank` ';
                      //execute the query using mysql_query
                      $result = mysql_query($query);
                      //then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)); {
                          echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' /></td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td>\n";
                      }   
echo <<<EOT
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



<script language="javscript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
ob_end_flush();
?>
```